# Very weird result of CTEs and subqueries

Tags: subquery, cte

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT a.id,
                   AVG(standard_qty) std_avg,
                   AVG(poster_qty) pos_avg,
                   AVG(glossy_qty) gloss_avg
            FROM accounts a
            JOIN orders o
            ON a.id = o.account_id
            GROUP BY 1),

     t2 AS (SELECT MAX(std_avg) max_std_avg,
                   MAX(pos_avg) max_pos_avg , 
                   MAX(gloss_avg) max_gloss_avg
            FROM t1)

SELECT std_id , max_std_avg, pos_id , max_pos_avg, glos_id , max_gloss_avg
FROM(SELECT
        (SELECT id std_id  FROM t1,t2 WHERE std_avg = max_std_avg),
        (SELECT id pos_id  FROM t1,t2 WHERE pos_avg = max_pos_avg),
        (SELECT id glos_id FROM t1,t2 WHERE gloss_avg =max_gloss_avg)
    )foo ,t1,t2
```

**RESULT:**

```
std_id  | max_std_avg| pos_id | max_pos_avg | glos_id |  max_gloss_avg     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1341 | 1891.7777  |   4251 | 2184.4615   |    4211 | 523.258
   1341 | 1891.7777  |   4251 | 2184.4615   |    4211 | 523.258
'
'
'
'
'
   1341 | 1891.7777  |   4251 | 2184.4615   |    4211 | 523.258
(350 ROWS)
```

However, the output should be only 1 single row:

```
std_id  | max_std_avg| pos_id | max_pos_avg | glos_id |  max_gloss_avg     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1341 | 1891.7777  |   4251 | 2184.4615   |    4211 | 523.258
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can explain why?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, now it works, but can you explain pls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the last, external query you cross join `foo` with `t1` and `t2`, while you only need (and use) columns from `foo` and `t2`.

So remove the `t1` join:

```
WITH 
    ...
SELECT
FROM (
     ...
     ) foo, t2 ;
```

---

The whole external query could be simplified further, as you don't really need the `t2` used four times, in the three subqueries plus the main query. You can use it once and still join it to `t1` three times:

```
WITH t1 AS ...,
     t2 AS ...
SELECT std.id   AS std_id,   t2.max_std_avg, 
       pos.id   AS pos_id,   t2.max_pos_avg, 
       gloss.id AS gloss_id, t2.max_gloss_avg
FROM t2
     JOIN t1 AS std   ON std  .std_avg   = t2.max_std_avg
     JOIN t1 AS pos   ON pos  .pos_avg   = t2.max_pos_avg
     JOIN t1 AS gloss ON gloss.gloss_avg = t2.max_gloss_avg
;
```

---

Another way to get the same results but in a slightly different format (3 rows instead of 1), would be to not use joins at all but more window functions. You could also:

- combine the two CTEs into one.
- remove the `accounts` from the first CTE. If there is a `FOREIGN KEY` from `orders` to `accounts`, the results will be the same.

The new query:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT account_id,
                   AVG(standard_qty) AS std_avg,
                   AVG(poster_qty)   AS pos_avg,
                   AVG(glossy_qty)   AS gloss_avg,

                   MAX(AVG(standard_qty)) OVER () AS max_std_avg,
                   MAX(AVG(poster_qty))   OVER () AS max_pos_avg , 
                   MAX(AVG(glossy_qty))   OVER () AS max_gloss_avg
            FROM orders o
            GROUP BY account_id)

SELECT t1.*, 
       CASE WHEN std_avg   = max_std_avg
           THEN 'max_std_avg'   ELSE NULL
       END AS std_result,
       CASE WHEN pos_avg   = max_pos_avg
           THEN 'max_pos_avg'   ELSE NULL
       END AS pos_result,
       CASE WHEN gloss_avg = max_gloss_avg
           THEN 'max_gloss_avg' ELSE NULL
       END AS gloss_result
FROM t1
WHERE std_avg   = max_std_avg
   OR pos_avg   = max_pos_avg
   OR gloss_avg = max_gloss_avg ;
```

Comment: Yes it should be simple